# Call private function when passing function as argument in function?

Tags: javascript, function, frameworks, private

I'm creating a javascript framework, and the code below is not working for some reason. Any reason why?

```
function jCamp(code){
   function test(){
      alert();
   }
  code();
}
jCamp(function(){
  test();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the scope with call or appy:

```
function jCamp(code){
   function test(){
      alert();
   }
  code.call(test);
}
jCamp(function(){
  this();
});
```

So we change `this` to reference the private function

Answer (score 1):

**test()** that is invoked inside the anonymous function that is argument to **jCamp()** is not defined (that's the one on line 8 if you won't change your code).  The function **test()** is only defined inside the definition of **jCamp()**.

Comment: then is there anyway to make it so a function is only callable through the argument function of jCamp()?

Answer (score 0):

```
function jCamp(code){
   this.test = function(){
      alert("test");
   }
  code();
}
jCamp(function(){
  this.test();
});
```

I would do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

`test` is a private function that can only be used within `jCamp`. You cannot call it from an anonymous function passed as an argument. You can make it a property though, like this:

```
function jCamp(code){
   this.test = function(){
      alert();
   }
  code();
}
jCamp(function(){
  this.test();
});
```

Comment: Beware that this will actually store `test` globally, as `this` is `window`.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a function is determined when it is **created**, not when it is called.

```
var a = 1; // This is the a that will be alerted
function foo(arg) {
        var a = 2;
        arg();
}
foo(function () { alert(a); });
```